# How to balance contrls using ArrangeOverride and MeasureOverride

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-interface, custom-controls, blend

I have created a custom panel to help understand the MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride methods. I want the odd items to show up on the left and the even numbered items to show up on the right.

```
1 - 0
3 - 2
5 - 3
7 - 4
    8
```

```
public class MyPanel : Panel
{
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        var mySize = new Size();
        foreach (UIElement child in this.InternalChildren)
        {
            child.Measure(availableSize);
            mySize.Width =  child.DesiredSize.Width * 2;
            var itemCount = Math.Ceiling(InternalChildren.Count / 2f);
            mySize.Height = itemCount  * child.DesiredSize.Height;
        }
        return mySize;
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        var odd = InternalChildren.OfType<UIElement>()
            .Where((c, i) => i % 2 != 0);
        var even = InternalChildren.OfType<UIElement>()
            .Where((c, i) => i % 2 == 0);

        var location = new Point();

        foreach (var child in even)
        {
            child.Arrange(new Rect(location, child.DesiredSize));
            location.X = child.DesiredSize.Width;
            location.Y += child.DesiredSize.Height;
            Debug.WriteLine(location);
        }
        
        location = new Point();
        foreach (var child in odd)
        {
            child.Arrange(new Rect(location, child.DesiredSize));
            location.Y += child.DesiredSize.Height;
            Debug.WriteLine(location);
        }

        return finalSize;
    }
}
```

Here is the markup for the panel.

```
<Canvas>
    <local:MyPanel x:Name="MyPanel1" Canvas.Left="500" Canvas.Top="200" 
       Background="#FFE84B4B">
    <Button Content="0"></Button>
    <Button Content="1"></Button>
    <Button Content="2"></Button>
    <Button Content="3"></Button>
    <Button Content="4"></Button>
    <Button Content="5"></Button>
    <Button Content="6"></Button>
    <Button Content="7"></Button>
    <Button Content="8"></Button>
</local:MyPanel>
</Canvas>
```

and here is the result

[image]

How can I get item 0 to show up and line up with the 1 column?

Comment: You may want to explain what it is supposed to do. Then we would not have to guess that from reading your code. Tell us what exactly does not work as expected.

Comment: item0 is exactly under item1 because you assign location.X after you arrange item `child.Arrange(new Rect(location, child.DesiredSize)); location.X = child.DesiredSize.Width;`. set X once, before loop. but it works *only if* all items have equal size which is not always the case

Comment: In the first call of `child.Arrange(new Rect(location, child.DesiredSize));` the value of `location.X` is obviously 0.

Comment: It makes no sense at all to set `location.X = child.DesiredSize.Width;` since `X` is determined by the width of the item left of child - or all items on the left.

Comment: You could as well achieve this with a UniformGrid with two Columns and FlowDirection RightToLeft.

Comment: if I move   "location.X = child.DesiredSize.Width;" to the first statement of the first loop it works as intended but I have work it out because I am not clear. Thanks for your help.

Comment: As said, it is wrong anyway. It works by accident because all items seem to have the same width.

Answer (score -1):

I'd first arrange the items on the left (the 'odds') because they define the horizontal offset. Then use that offset for the 'evens'.
Of course this is just kind of demo code. DesiredSize isn't RenderSize. As soon as the DP-system calculates a diff between the two the fixed positioning proofs too rigid.

```
    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        var odd = InternalChildren.OfType<UIElement>()
                                  .Where((c, i) => i % 2 != 0);
        var even = InternalChildren.OfType<UIElement>()
                                   .Where((c, i) => i % 2 == 0);

        var location       = new Point();
        foreach (var child in odd)
        {
            child.Arrange(new Rect(location, child.DesiredSize));
            location.Y += child.DesiredSize.Height;
            Debug.WriteLine(location);
        }

        var evenHorzOffset = odd.First().DesiredSize.Width;
        location = new Point(evenHorzOffset, 0);

        foreach (var child in even)
        {
            child.Arrange(new Rect(location, child.DesiredSize));
            location.Y += child.DesiredSize.Height;
            Debug.WriteLine(location);
        }

        return finalSize;
    }
```